# Import error while trying to import ydata profiling

Tags: python, pandas, importerror, pandas-profiling

I have installed ydata but I'm unable to import profile report, it's showing ProfileReport isn't accessed. I've updated pandas version, anaconda version and all other dependencies. If anyone knows please help!

I also tried to import ydata_profiling but that too didn't work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others. Also include the complete error message you get.

Comment: How do you expect us to help without showing your code??  The problem could be literally almost anything.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide some code of what you are attempting?

Ideally, you would first create a virtual environment with conda and install ydata-profiling:

```
conda create -n synth-env python=3.10
conda activate synth-env
pip install ydata-profiling==4.1.2
```

Then, in your Jupyter Notebook or other editor (e.g., PyCharm), load your Pandas DataFrame as you normally would and the generation of the profiling report is straightforward:

```
import pandas as pd
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport

# Read the data from a csv file
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

# Generate the data profiling report 
report = ProfileReport(df, title='Original Data')
report.to_file("profiling_report.html")
```